# inject the output of the network into the input layer of the next time step

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build an LSTM network using quarterly time series, making a forecast named yt (0 or 1) for each quarter. Here is the network I am currently using:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(40, activation='tanh',return_sequences = False,input_shape=(x2.shape[1],x2.shape[2]), kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42)))
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False,name="binary_crossentropy",),optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.PrecisionAtRecall(0.85)])
history = model.fit(x2, y2, epochs=160, batch_size=50,  verbose=1, shuffle=False, validation_data=(x2_v, y2_v))
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Loss')
```

yt-1 is the variable that most impacts the forecast of 0 or 1 for yt. The problem is that this yt-1 is not known in t, this value can only be observed 8 quarters later. So I can't use yt-1 in practice to make my forecast. What I would like to do is to inject the forecast made by the network at the previous time step into the set of variables of the input layer at the next time step, as in the diagram below.
For the prediction on the validation and test data I can handle this problem with a loop but I don't know how to adapt this mechanism during training.
I have also tried to train my network without using this variable but the performance remains poor despite tuning the parameters. Is there a way to build something similar to the scheme with Keras and one or more LSTM layers?

[image: Neural network I would like to build]

Comment: you just need to lookup on google "teacher forcing tensorflow"

Comment: I have already tried this method (without knowing it was called like that), it gives good results in validation but does not generalise well. This method is not the best here because given that yt-1 is the most determinant variable of yt when I use the true value of yt-1 instead of the last prediction performed by the model, the network is not trained to correct its prediction error (in this study the 1 correspond to signals and therefore follow each other in time). But while learning more about the teacher learning method I found other like Curriculum Learning which i'm gonna try. Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean... the validation set performance is used to estimate the generalization capability of the network... thus, good validation performance leads generally to good generalization of the model... Curriculum learning afaik has not much to do with teacher forcing...

Comment: I use 4 validation samples included in my training sample because I use the expanding window method (I work with time series with little history). These validation samples allow me to tune the parameters during training but it is the performance on the test sample that interests me, guaranteeing a good generalization of the model since this sample is further in time from the training sample than my last validation sample.

Comment: The approach is called curriculum learning and involves randomly choosing to use the ground truth output or the generated output from the previous time step as input for the current time step. So it is a mix between teacher forcing (uses the true value) and the default method (uses the last prediction).

Comment: curriculum learning has foundation in preprocessing, giving your model always tougher samples/task. However, you probably have a dataset that is too small if you only have 4 validation sample. Also, if you have a fixed time window, RNN are not the best choice, for example you can check out WaveNet that uses a FFNN with 1D convolution and outperforms RNN